# Re-run with -feature for details

Tags: scala, playframework

When I compile scala in play console, I got this:

```
[warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
```

I thought it means `compile -feature`, but I got this:

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: compile (similar: completions)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '::'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] compile -feature
[error]
```

Then I run `play -feature`, I got this:

```
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
```

And play quit.

So how should I do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to add

```
scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

to your `build.sbt` and execute `reload` if your sbt console is running (or restart it).

Alternatively if you want to set it only for a single session, while in sbt console.

```
set scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

You can write, this setting is applied immediately, no need to reload or restart sbt console.

Answer (score 10):

Just for completion if you're in the play/sbt repl you can modify the value of `scalacOptions` just for the session, like this:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same warning and have changed the scala options as mentioned in the comments. However I am unable to get rid of the warning. What is the root cause of this error?

Comment: Same issue here :(

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found the source of my error to the file /usr/local/etc/sbtopts. It had the following line added at the end by some program I had installed.

```
-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

Whenever sbt launches the above line is passed as arguments which was causing the above error. As these are java options to solve it either we can add -J before the above line or delete the line completely. This gets rid of -feature.

Comment: For me this was in the IntelliJ compiler options, not even in the SBT config, but it amounts to the same thing. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

The flag needs to be added to Scala compiler options. You can do this by adding the following line to your `build.sbt` file:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")
```

Comment: Any idea what this flag does ?