# Scala: The `-` [dash, minus] command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0

Tags: scala, sbt, scalac

When I'm doing `sbt compile -feature` on my Scala project I get a mysterious warnings:

```
The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
```

I have no clue what that dash/minus command is or where it is possibly being used. Searching for it on google is impossible, as well as grepping the code base for it (There are just /so/ /many/ /dashes/).

If at least I knew where it is defined. I could not find anything in the scala doc either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play, re-run with -feature for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926515/play-re-run-with-feature-for-details)

Comment: it took me a little bit to actually understand that this is a duplicate, but it most certainly is :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for this:

```
// commands with poor choices for names since they clash with the usual conventions for command line options
//   these are not documented and are mainly internal commands and can be removed without a full deprecation cycle
object Compat {
    def OnFailure = "-"
    ...
    def OnFailureDeprecated = deprecatedAlias(OnFailure, BasicCommandStrings.OnFailure)
    ...
    private[this] def deprecatedAlias(oldName: String, newName: String): String =
        s"The `$oldName` command is deprecated in favor of `$newName` and will be removed in 0.14.0"
}
```

[Source here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/BasicCommandStrings.scala.html)

Also, kind-of related question and pieces of information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23926515/1180426), especially how to add the `-feature` to scalac options.

Comment: Now I get what is going on... the -feature flag is required by scalac not sbt which is invoking scalac.. alright :-)