# SBT not entering interactive mode

Tags: scala, sbt

I installed sbt using Homebrew and it installed correctly. I am able to build projects and do all sbt tasks. However when I try to enter sbt interactive mode it shows the below and exits. For everything else sbt works fine.

```
[info] Set current project to sbt_test (in build file:/Users/binshi/sbt_test/)
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
```

Comment: What exactly do you type in the command prompt to enter interactive mode? All you have to do is type `sbt`

Comment: Yes, all I type is sbt. Then the above message and instead of stopping at > prompt it exits.

Comment: Could you perhaps share the contents of your `build.sbt`, especially the `scalacOptions` part?

Comment: This question looks related to your problem: [Play, re-run with -feature for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926515/play-re-run-with-feature-for-details)

Comment: I saw the comments in the link before. Shouldn't the sbt command run right off the sbt package before a project is created? Hence it does not contain build.sbt or scalacOptions.

Comment: You should run it from the root directory of your project.

Comment: I ran it from the root directory of the project. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I found the source of my error to the file /usr/local/etc/sbtopts. It had the following line added at the end by some program I had installed.

```
-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

Whenever sbt launches the above line is passed as arguments which was causing the above error. As these are java options to solve it either we can add -J before the above line or delete the line completely. Then sbt should start working normally.